# How to pass renewed token asynchronously in accessTokenFactory in SignalR?

Tags: jquery, .net, asp.net-core, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I want to pass the renewed token into SignalR requests every time it expires, so that authentication works all the time. And since I have to get the token by an ajax call, from Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/configuration?view=aspnetcore-5.0&tabs=dotnet#configure-bearer-authentication) we can achieve this by using **accessTokenFactory().**

```
let connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
.withUrl("/chathub", {
    accessTokenFactory: () => {
    // Get and return the access token.
    // This function can return a JavaScript Promise if asynchronous
    // logic is required to retrieve the access token.
    }
 })
.build();
```

But in the below code, if I write the ajax GET call inside the accessTokenFactory function, then it doesn't wait for it to finish (since it is an ajax call) and is calling the server and authentication is failing since the token is not yet present in the query string.

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
                    .withUrl(baseUrl + 'hub/report?groupName=' + groupName, {
                        skipNegotiation: true,
                        transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
                        accessTokenFactory: () =>                            
                        {
                            $.get('api/user/getAccessToken/')
                                .done(function (token) {
                                    return token;;
                                })
                        }
                        }
                    )
                    .withAutomaticReconnect()
                    .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
                    .build();
```

Can you tell me how to write a ajax call inside the accessTokenFactory function such that it waits for ajax call to finish or **how to return a promise (as mentioned in the Microsoft doc code above)** in jQuery/JavaScript so that the renewed token is passed along with every SignalR request?

*Note: I can use JavaScript or jQuery in my client code.*

Comment: Try to use [jQuery.ajax()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/) to call the `getAccessToken` method and set the `async` option to `false`, then, the request will be synchronous operation. More detail information, you could check [the document](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/#jQuery-ajax-settings) and pay attention to the note.

Comment: @ZhiLv I don't want to use async false as it is deprecated and not encouraged to be used anymore. Is there any other option to work it out with a ajax promise?

Comment: You could try to use the `jQuery.when()` method, it accepts any number of Deferred or Promise objects as arguments and executes a function when all of them resolve. More detail information, see [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/).

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can achieve this by **promisifying** the ajax call in conjunction with making the accessTokenFactory callback asynchronous:

```
var connection = new signalR.HubConnectionBuilder()
  .withUrl(baseUrl + 'hub/report?groupName=' + groupName, {
    skipNegotiation: true,
    transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
    accessTokenFactory: async () => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        $.get('api/user/getAccessToken/').done((token) => resolve(token));
      });
    },
  })
  .withAutomaticReconnect()
  .configureLogging(signalR.LogLevel.Debug)
  .build();
```